# DatePicker Format Changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I was looking to change format of Datepicker in HTML using script. The current format is: `MM/DD//YYYY`

I am able to change it to the required one (`DD/MM/YYYY`) using the following script. On the desktop version it's perfect. However as I use it on mobile too, it seems like both formats are showing in the field after selecting a date. On top, it shows `DD/MM/YYYY` and just under it shows `MM/DD//YYYY` (overlapping each other, seems like input box does not remove the old value).

```js
$("input").on("change", function() {
  this.setAttribute("data-date",moment(this.value, "YYYY-MM-DD").format(this.getAttribute("data-date-format")))
}).trigger("change")
```

```css
input {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  color: white;
}

input:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  content: attr(data-date);
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
}

input::-webkit-datetime-edit,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input::-webkit-clear-button {
  display: none;
}

input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 0;
  color: black;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" data-date="" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY" value="2015-08-09">
```

Comment: I have tried the same code on my system but didn't get an issue. Show us a screenshot of what error you are getting. Also, if you are trying to customize date picker or change formats, you can use date pickers like Bootstrap Datepiccker.

Comment: Yes on desktop version its working 100% perfect. but look in screenshot, as i open in mobile version (chrome S9+), it shows selected date DD/MM/YYYY in dark, just behind it it shows same select date MM/DD/YYYY format in white color. link is https://www.dropbox.com/s/wphqddxdw86umbg/dateissue.jpg?dl=0